# perfernce Sacreen color picker library unable to implement in android studioH

Tags: java, android, github

Hello friends  i am beginner and using this library  implementation'com.github.kizitonwose.colorpreference:core:'
library link is here   https://github.com/kizitonwose/colorpreference

in my project for perfernceSacreen the problem is that when i tried implement this library in my project it give me this exception:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.kizitonwose.colorpreference:core:<latest-version>.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.kizitonwose.colorpreference:core:<latest-version>.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.kizitonwose.colorpreference:core:<latest-version>.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

my dependecies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'petrov.kristiyan:colorpicker-library:1.1.5'

    implementation 'com.github.kizitonwose.colorpreference:core:<latest-version>'
    implementation   'com.yokkomi:seekbar-preference:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.infideap.drawerbehavior:drawer-behavior:0.1.5'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem while using Toasty library.And realized that its because of a version mismatch.Try suitable version of Android.I recommend you to get the latest version!